# Using map instead of if/else condition

Tags: vue.js

I need to validate over 100 fields.Is there an efficient way to do this instead of using if/else or switch statement.I have seen people are using map.How can i achieve that.

```
if (value === 'firstName') {
    if (this.firstName === null) {
      this.errorFirstName = true;
      this.errorMsgFirstName = 'First name required';
    } else if (this.firstName.length > 25) {
      this.errorFirstName = true;
      this.errorMsgFirstName = 'First name invalid'
    } else {
      this.errorFirstName = false;
      this.errorMsgFirstName = null;
    }
  }
  if (value === 'lastName') {
    if (this.lastName === null) {
      this.errorlastName = true;
      this.errorMsgLastName = 'Last name required';
    } else if (this.lastName.length > 25) {
      this.errorLastName = true;
      this.errorMsgLastName = 'Last name invalid'
    } else {
      this.errorLastName = false;
      this.errorMsgLastName = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: "I have seen people are using map" - what exactly do you mean? In case you have an idea what the code should look like, what did you try then? The code doesn't make sense without the context, it's unknown how validation works in your case There should be objects that use field names (firstName, etc) as dynamic keys to keep the code as dry as possible and avoid mentioning field-specific keys like errorFirstName, that's all that can be said at this point.

Comment: tip, rather then doing errorFirstName and errorMsgFirstName and 200 more other variables, you should have a single errors object then add to it, i.e `form.errors.firstname`, then you only need do `if (Object.keys(this.form.errors).lenght) return`, then inside the view you can do `v-if="form.errors.firstname"` to show the errors